# How to use actuator endpoints programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I need some metrics in to the spring boot application. So I used MetricsEndpoint like below. But I can't access to metrics. invoke() method does not appear.

spring boot version: 2.2.6.RELEASE

```
@Controller
public class DashboardControllerImpl implements IDashboardController {

    @Autowired
    private MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity listDiskUsage() {
        metricsEndpoint.invoke(); // invoke does not appear

        // code block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some thing like that, that solved my problem!

```
((MetricsEndpoint.Sample)metricsEndpoint.metric("process.uptime", null).getMeasurements().get(0)).getValue()
```